# Effective Field Theories of QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

Recently, I am studying the online course [Effective Field Theory](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-851-effective-field-theory-spring-2013/) provided by MIT OCW. Prof. Stewart gives a nice [picture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-851-effective-field-theory-spring-2013/8-851s13.jpg) to summarize the effective theories:

[image: Example Effective Field Theories derived from Quantum Field Theory]

As a newbie in this field (I only have a knowledge of QFT on the level of Peskin & Schroeder's book), I am quite confused with so many terminologies. What do they stand for and Why do we need these different theories? Could someone explain this picture in depth (especially on their advantages and limitations)? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @soliton: If you've made any progress in the course, you might be able to answer your own question. I think it will help many others :-)